# Removing repeated, nonpunctuation character from a string

Tags: r

I have a string in R with several, non-punctuation repeated characters (a pound sign). I am trying to remove the repeatedness of the pound sign "#" but keep only one to separate the words in the string. The number of pound signs between words is random and is not always the same.

For example:

```
String="##Hello####World#Happy#######New###Ye@r!"
```

transform into

```
String_New="#Hello#World#Happy#New#Ye@r!"
```

Does the gsub command handle non-punctuation signs?

Comment: Try `gsub("#+", "#", String)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to specify `+` ie. one or more characters to match and in the replacement add a single `#`

```
gsub("#+", "#", String)
#[1] "#Hello#World#Happy#New#Ye@r!"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for respond. It worked! Any reason why we added a "+" sign?

Comment: I found another example here on Stackoverflow that also had a "+" but included a "1" and backslashes "\\". Hard to tell when to include which. Here is the example:  gsub('([[:alpha:]])\\1+', '\\1', 'Buenaaaaaaaaa Suerrrrte')

Comment: @jessica It depends on what the OP wants as expected output.  Based on the input here, it is only the `#` characters that are repeated.  Suppose if if you have the other characters repeated as well and want to change, then have to modify accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to do what you want:

```
a <- "##Hello####World#Happy#######New###Year"
b <- gsub('#######', '#', a)
b <- gsub('###', '#', b)
b <- gsub('##', '#', b)
```

And yes you can handle nonpunction signs as well if you desire.